# Some error with factory method pattern in WCF. Can anyone point my error?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, factory-pattern

I have a factory design method implemented in my WCF but there is some error in this line i guess:

```
return svc.Calculation(int value1 + int value2);
```

Here are my other codes:

```
namespace CompositeWCF
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int Calculation(int value1, int value2, string calType)
    {
        try
        {
          IService1 svc;

          switch (calType)
            {
                case "addition":
                    svc = new addition();

                case "subtraction":

                    svc = new subtraction();

                case "multiplication":

                    svc = new multiplication();

                case "division":
                    svc = new division();

            }

          return svc.Calculation(int value1 + int value2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

There are four classes for "addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", "division"

there codes are similar to this

```
    namespace CompositeWCF
    {
    class addition:IService1
    {
        public int Calculation(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }
    }
}
```

this is supposed to get user input that is two values and the calculation type and use those to perform calculation from the specific class.

Comment: Here's an important lesson to learn early. Don't use `ex.Message` if you want to learn what happened. Use `ex.ToString()` which includes all the information you're likely to need.

Comment: BTW, the "factory" part of this is just the part that determines `svc`. The rest is just calling an operation on a service.

Comment: thanks john good point...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: Saying "I guess there's an error on this line" and not actually supplying the error.. will get you downvotes. If I were to copy and paste a huge bulk of code to you and say "theres an error. Please find it".. would you be able to?

But, because your error is quite obvious.. here is my answer:

```
return svc.Calculation(int value1 + int value2);
                       ^^^          ^^^
                // Remove this     Remove this
```

Also, as pointed out by David in the comments, the function takes two separate arguments:

```
return svc.Calculation(value1, value2);
```

You don't need to include a type name when returning a variable.. only when declaring one. You may come across casting at some point, which would look like this:

```
return svc.Calculation((int)value1, (int)value2);
// Notice the parenthesis
```

..however, you don't need to in your example.

Comment: I did add a thing about inconsistent braces.. however it appears to be your indentation making my eyes hurt :(

Comment: Hi simon thanks for the answer it did go ahead from that problem but it says use of unassigned local variable 'svc', and 'CompositeWCF.Service1' does not implement interface member 'CompositeWCF.IService1.Calculation(int,int)' it only shows when i put braces. If i dont the error is same as i asked the question about. Got any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Learn C# basics first. Then move to some advanced stuff!

Comment: since Calculation take 2 parameters, shouldn't the + be a ,...like __return svc.Calculation(value1, value2);__

Comment: @BikramGc - Service1 doesn't implement Calculation(int, int), it implements Calculation(int, int, string)...so the error is correct there

Comment: @DavidHope Good pick up.. I didn't actually look that far down. Thanks for that :)

Comment: thanks @DavidHope there is some issue going on i did try that but can't get on with it

Comment: @BikramGc These are all very simple errors that are easily decipherable given the completion of a C# book/course. I would definitely suggest either of the two (or both).